# error no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list c++

Tags: c++, iostream, getline

error no instance of overloaded function "getline" matches the argument list

I cant seem to see what is wrong. I feel like I am passing the correct arguments (ie the `std::ofstream` and the `std::string`). Any help would be great thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  ofstream yourFile;
  myfile.open ("read.cc");
  yourFile.open ("write.cpp");
  string line;
```

This section in particular is the one that is getting an error.

```
  if (myfile.is_open()){
```

The getline in the while loop is red and is giving me the overload error.

```
      while(getline(myfile,line)){
          yourFile << line <<"\n";
      }
  }

  myfile.close();
  yourFile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I thought I had set up the streams correctly.

Answer (score 3):

An output stream is for writing to. For reading from, you want an input stream:

```
std::ifstream myFile;
//   ^^
```